# How to format a dollar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

I am doing a divide and multiply to figure out the value of a field and the value looks like this

```
$32560.000000000004.00
```

I am setting the value like this

```
sq_footage = $("#sq_footage").val();
sq_footage_total = (((sq_footage / 36) * factor) * average )* 30;
if(factor != ""){
    $("#new_calc").val("$" + sq_footage_total + ".00");
}
```

Is there a way to format it like

```
$32,560.00
```

Comment: From quick Google search: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/currency-money-format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=jquery+currency+format&aq=0p&aqi=p-p2g3&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7baa05c8a727054d

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been solved before, but here's my solution just for fun:

```
function formatDollar(num) {
    var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
    return ["$", p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i) {
        return num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "."), p[1]].join("");
}
```

And some tests:

```
formatDollar(45664544.23423) // "$45,664,544.23"
formatDollar(45) // "$45.00"
formatDollar(123) // "$123.00"
formatDollar(7824) // "$7,824.00"
formatDollar(1) // "$1.00"
formatDollar(939,009) // ?
```

```js
function formatDollar(num) {
      var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
      return ["$", p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i) {
        return num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
      }, "."), p[1]].join("");
    }


    const tests = [
      {
        input: 45664544.23423,
        expected: "$45,664,544.23"
      },
      {
        input: 45,
        expected: "$45.00"
      },
      {
        input: 123,
        expected: "$123.00"
      },
      {
        input: 7824,
        expected: "$7,824.00"
      },
      {
        input: 1,
        expected: "$1.00"
      },
      {
        input: -939009,
        expected: "-$939,009.00"
      }
    ]

    tests.forEach(test => {
      const { input, expected } = test
      const actual = formatDollar(input)
      if (expected !== actual) {
        console.log(`Failed: ${input}. Expected ${expected}; actual: ${actual}`)
      } else {
        console.log(`Passed: ${input}`)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tag indicates that you are using jquery - so you might use the [jQuery Format Currency Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/)